# Set max result query in Hibernate, Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Help me please.
Database is PostgreSQL, + Java + Hibernate.
In base №1 there is a table №1 in which there are 4 million lines. Also there is a base number №2 in it there is a table №2 in which there are 61 000 lines.
There is a working code:

```
    @Override
public List<UserStatisticDto> findGroupedByUser(final PageInfoDto pageInfo) {
   final Query query = buildSortQuery(pageInfo.sort, StatisticEventEntity.FIND_GROUPED_BY_USER_QUERY, StatisticEventEntity.FIND_GROUPED_BY_USER);
    query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(20);
    List<UserStatisticDto> list = toUserStatisticDto(query.getResultList());
    return getSubList(list, pageInfo);
}

private Query buildSortQuery(final SortInfoDto[] sort, final String sortQuery, final String nonSortQuery) {
        Query query;
        if(sort != null && sort.length > 0) {
            String queryString = sortQuery;
            query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
        } else {
            query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(nonSortQuery);
        }
        return query;
    }

    private List getSubList(List list, final PageInfoDto pageInfo){
        int startIndex = (pageInfo.pageNumber) * pageInfo.pageSize;
        int lastIndex = startIndex+ pageInfo.pageSize + 1;
        if (lastIndex > list.size()){
            return list.subList(startIndex, list.size());
        }
        return list.subList(startIndex, lastIndex);
    }
```

There is class PageInfoDto:

```
public class PageInfoDto implements Serializable {
    public int pageNumber = 0;
    public int pageSize = 20;
    public SortInfoDto[] sort;

    public PageInfoDto() {
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return this.pageNumber * this.pageSize;
    }
}
```

there is a query to the database and getting statistics on the table. In the database №2 in which 61 000 lines the sampling is done perfectly. In the database №1 in which there are 4 million lines of sampling is done about 10 minutes...

Despite the fact that I wrote, it still does not work. We have to wait about 10 minutes.

The request is sent and the answer is formed for a very long time.
Can you please tell me how to limit the maximum threshold at which the hibernate will not unload all 4 million lines from the database at once?

How can I make the hibernate unload only the required amount of data?
On the page.html, there is a table in which 20 lines are placed.
Help me please, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a giant block of text. It'll be easier to understand if you formatted it better.

Comment: @abc I'm sorry, but I don't understand you correctly. What do you mean, tell me please

Comment: Enable SQL logging in Hibernate and check your SQL queries. Is LIMIT specified in the query?

Comment: Edit your question and separate the big paragraph into smaller ones so it's easier to read and understand your question.

Comment: @PavelMolchanov my HQL in code: "select e.user, e.eventType, count(e) from StatisticEventEntity e WHERE e.college.deleted=false group by e.user, e.eventType";